# How can I set app title after loading UI using Gtk.Builder() in python?

Tags: python, gtk, title

I'm trying to set the app title using set_wmclass but I'm getting a Gtk-WARNING and finally app name is not set.

> Gtk-WARNING **: gtk_window_set_wmclass: shouldn't set wmclass after
>   window is realized!

I'm using Gtk.Builder() to load the window UI from a glade file like this...

```
ui_builder = Gtk.Builder()
ui_builder.add_from_file('window.ui')
window = ui_builder.get_object('window1')
self.__window.set_wmclass("Hello World", "Hello World")
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `GLib.set_application_name()` instead.

Comment: set_title() sets the window title, I'm trying to change the app name, the title that you can see next to Activities hot corner on GNOME3.

Answer (score 0):

I finally create a GtkWindow like `__window = Gtk.Window()` and then I added other UI components (a GtkBox) with a GtkBuilder.